# Concatenate a list of AnnData objects

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

An [AnnData](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) object is comprised of `matrix` (ie. dataframe), `anndata.obs` and `anndata.var` Pandas dataframes.

I have several subdirectories that might contain `matrix.mtx.gz`, `features.tsv.gz`, `barcodes.tsv.gz`. Here, the `matrix` corresponds to data matrix, the `obs` corresponds with `features`, whereas `var` corresponds with `barcodes`. A combination of these three files/dataframe forms a single AnnData object.

For each of the subdirectories, I want to form a separate AnnData object by appending `obs` and `var` from `features.tsv.gz` and `barcodes.tsv.gz`, respectively, to the pandas dataframe `matrix` from `matrix.mtx.gz`.

Finally, combine all the AnnData objects using [`anndata.concat`](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/anndata.concat.html) into a single AnnData object `ref`.

**However, my code produced an AnnData object `ref` with only `obs` and `var` names but without any of the column/row values.**

Code:

```
import anndata as ad
import os
import pandas as pd
import scanpy as sc
import warnings

# Initialize ref as an AnnData object
ref = None

# Filter out FutureWarnings temporarily
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

# Iterate through subdirectories
for subdir_name in os.listdir(ref_path):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(ref_path, subdir_name)

    # Check if required files exist
    required_files = ['matrix.mtx.gz', 'features.tsv.gz', 'barcodes.tsv.gz']
    if not all(os.path.exists(os.path.join(subdir_path, file)) for file in required_files):
        print(f"Skipping {subdir_name} due to missing files.")
        continue

    # Matrix
    matrix_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, 'matrix.mtx.gz')
    matrix = sc.read_mtx(matrix_path)  # Assuming matrix.mtx.gz is the matrix file
    sample_id = subdir_name

    # Features
    features = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir_path, 'features.tsv.gz'), header=None, sep="\t")

    # Barcodes
    barcodes = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir_path, 'barcodes.tsv.gz'), header=None)

    # Check if the number of barcodes matches the number of observations in the matrix
    if matrix.shape[1] != len(barcodes):
        print(f"Warning: Number of barcodes does not match the number of observations in {subdir_name}")
        continue

    # Set obs_names to features
    matrix.obs_names = features[0]
    matrix.obs_names_make_unique()

    # Set var_names to barcodes
    matrix.var_names = barcodes[0]
    matrix.var_names_make_unique()
    
    # Concatenate individual AnnData objects to form the final ref object
    if ref is None:
        ref = matrix.copy()
    else:
        ref = ad.concat([ref, matrix], axis=1)

# Reset the filterwarnings
warnings.resetwarnings()
```

Sample input structure (from one of the subdirectories):

`matrix`

```
AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 29305 × 46958
```

`features`

```
pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'ENSG00000121410',
  1: 'ENSG00000268895',
  2: 'ENSG00000148584',
  3: 'ENSG00000175899',
  4: 'ENSG00000245105'},
 1: {0: 'A1BG', 1: 'A1BG-AS1', 2: 'A1CF', 3: 'A2M', 4: 'A2M-AS1'}})
```

`barcodes`

```
pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'GTAAATTGACTTGA-1',
  1: 'CTGATTGATTTCCT-1',
  2: 'ACGTAGCAACGTTG-1',
  3: 'AGCCCCATGCACGC-1',
  4: 'CGAGCCATGACACT-1'}})
```

Current output:

`ref`

```
AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 18511 × 1250975
```

`ref.obs`

```
pd.DataFrame({})
```

`ref.var`

```
{}
```